# How to set nproc for a single command?

Tags: bash

If you have a `test.sh` containing

```
make -j$(nproc)
```

How could you temporarily adjust nproc, along the lines of `nproc=1 ./test.sh`?

Comment: Why not change `test.sh` so that the number of processors is passed in the first parameter, and the `make` line becomes `make -j$1`? You can default to the current script action by preceding with `[ $# == 0 ] && set $(nproc)`.

Comment: Yeah really looking for a non-intrusive way though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a wrapper that prints `$nproc`:

```
#!/bin/sh
[ -z "$nproc" ] && exec /usr/bin/nproc "$@"
printf '%s\n' "$nproc"
```

Name it `nproc`, make it executable (`chmod +x nproc`) and place it in your `/special/directory` for custom wrappers. Now you have two options:

1. On demand:

   ```
   PATH="/special/directory:$PATH" nproc=1 ./test.sh
   ```
2. Permanent. Modify your `PATH` so `/special/directory` is always there as the first entry. Then you can just

   ```
   nproc=1 ./test.sh
   ```

Notes:

- If the script alters (resets, sanitizes) its `PATH`, the solution may not work.
- If the variable is empty or not set, the wrapper uses the real `nproc` (by its full path to avoid calling itself recursively). This way `nproc` will behave exactly as before, unless you set the variable to any non-empty value.
- In your example `$(nproc)` is not quoted. This means you can inject additional options via the variable (e.g. `nproc="2 -i"`, the wrapper will print this string, in the script it will be split into two words and `-i` will be passed to `make`). You may

  - take advantage of this and use the variable to actually inject options (hacky, not recommended);
  - always make sure the variable is sane;
  - implement some logic into the wrapper, so its output is less likely to be split; example:

    ```
    set -- $nproc
    printf '%s\n' "$1"
    # word splitting done in the wrapper, only the first word is printed
    ```
  - (proper solution) fix the script:

    ```
    make -j"$(nproc)"
    # if the wrapper prints unexpected string, make will comply
    ```

Comment: Any particular reason you used `printf '%s\n'` over just `echo`?

Comment: @Attie [General reasons](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/108618), good practice.

Answer (score 1):

If `test.sh` is a bash script, another way could be to export a function named `nproc`:

```
bash-5.0$ cat foo.sh
#! /bin/bash

echo make -j $(nproc)
bash-5.0$ ./foo.sh
make -j 8
```

Creating and exporting a function:

```
bash-5.0$ nproc() { echo function 10; }
bash-5.0$ (export -f nproc; ./foo.sh)
make -j function 10
```